# Accessing custom tableView cell property outside of tableview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a custom tableViewCell class that has a `UIImageView` as an `IBOutlet`.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView * waveformImageView;
```

I also have two view controllers: one with a tableView and one without a tableView.

I need to know the height and width of this `UIImageView` to send to another class to do a calculation in my NON tableView view controller

I tried doing the following in my header file of my view controller (view controller without a tableView)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) OSAudioTableCell * tableCell;
```

and then accessing the `UIImageView` property by doing the following in one of my methods:

```
self.tableCell = [[OSAudioTableCell alloc] init];    
[self.waveView setSize:self.tableCell.waveformImageView.bounds.size];
```

This is all done in my view controller that doesn't contain a tableView.  I'm pretty sure I'm doing this wrong since the width and height are coming out as zero.  I can get these values fine within my view controller which contains my tableView.

Comment: your code is just instantiating a new, empty, table cell, which is why you get 0.  You need to use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method on your tableview to get the specific tableview cell you are after, but you haven't given enough code to show how you transition to view controller 2 for a more detailed answer

Comment: Well, the next step uses the calculation to render a UIImage that is stored in a dictionary that is added to an array.  I then immediately call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToLibrary" sender:self];` which sends me to my view controller with my tableView where I access the dictionary with the Image `cell.waveformImageView.image = [packageInArray objectForKey:@"waveImage"];`  Is it possible to get the table cell imageView bounds in my non tableview view controller?  My whole intent is to do the calculation before I get to the tableView.

Comment: So do you trigger the segue from a row select event?  If so then please show your `didSelectRow:atIndexPath:` and `prepareForSegue` methods in your table view controller

Comment: No, all of this is done BEFORE I segue INTO the view controller with my tableView. So there is no row select event.

Comment: Well, unless you have fixed-height cells you can't know the height of the cell until the table view has been populated - at least you can't get the height property of the cell, as the cell doesn't exist